# How to update ag-grid-community from version 20.1.0 to 24.1.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Namely I am facing the following few errors, but when I try to look up from the AgGrid documentation, these attributes are no where to be found... They aren't even mentioned in the Change Log for deprecation...

Firstly, I am getting these compilation errors

> ERROR in : Can't bind to 'enableSorting' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
>
> ERROR in : Can't bind to 'enableSorting' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
>
> ERROR in : Can't bind to 'enableColResize' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.

```
// these 3 bindings are gone? I see no mentioned of them in change log, are they even on by default now?
<ag-grid-angular [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true" [enableColResize]="true">
```

Secondly, these are not in the `ag-grid-angular`'s `GridOptions` definition and similarly I can't find them on their documentation neither!!!

- suppressTabbing
- enableSorting
- enableServerSideSorting
- enableServerSideFilter

What is the usual migration approach some of you had experienced? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting and Filtering is now enabled via the Column Definition. So the type definitions will be found in `ColDef` and not in `GridOptions`.

Please see the following for [ColDef](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/community-modules/core/typings/entities/colDef.d.ts) definitions.

If you want to enable sorting / filtering / resize on a column, simply add the properties like this:

```
{ field:'athlete', sortable:true, filter:true, resizable:true }
```

Please see the [documentation on this here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/column-definitions/).

Comment: What about `suppressTabbing`?

Comment: To suppress keyboard events in the current version of ag-grid, you can do so by implementing the callback suppressKeyboardEvent, please see the documentation on this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/keyboard-navigation/#suppress-keyboard-events